# Solenoid not embeddable in plane

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I'm trying to find an reference (in English) that gives a proof that any $P$-adic solenoid (where $P$ is a sequence of prime numbers) cannot be embedded in the plane, $\mathbb{R}^2$.  So far, all the references seem to only say so, but they never give a proof.  I know Van Dantzig was the originator of the concept, but his paper is in German.  Can anyone help me find a paper or book that gives a proof and is written in English?

Answer (score 3):

Van Dantzig did introduce solenoids in

> van Dantzig, D.. ["Ueber topologisch homogene Kontinua."](https://eudml.org/doc/212336) *Fundamenta Mathematicae* 15.1 (1930): 102-125.

but at the time he did not comment on the question of their planarity.
Much later Bing published a result implying that they are not planar and this appears to be the first proof of that fact.

> Bing, R. H. ["A simple closed curve is the only homogeneous bounded plane continuum that contains an arc."](https://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1960-018-x) *Canad. J. Math* 12 (1960): 209-230.

Comment: and just last year, it was proved that every homogeneous plane continuum is a circle, pseudoarc, or circle of pseudoarcs https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11511-016-0138-0

Comment: Thank you very much! And yes @ForeverMozart , I'm aware of that paper, have it sitting somewhere in my desk.  Oversteegen actually came to where I am and gave a talk on the result.    Good stuff!