# Can a solenoid exist in the plane?

Tags: general-topology, continuum-theory

If $X$ is an $n$-dimensional continuum, then $X$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$.

So if $X$ is a solenoid, it can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, we even have a construction of this.

Is it possible for a solenoid to be embedded in the plane?

Comment: Do you mean [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics))?  If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: The "nuke for a fly" answer is that by a recent result of Hoehn-Oversteegeen homogeneous planar continua are classified (they are $S^1$, the pseudoarc and the circle of pseudoarcs), so solenoids aren't planar (unless you count $S^1$ as a solenoid). I'm sure there is a way to argue solenoids are not planar directly, but I'm not seeing it right now

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283930/solenoid-not-embeddable-in-plane turns out that the first proof of nonplanarity of solenoids is actually a partial result toward the classification I mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer to remove the question from the unanswered list.

Solenoids are known to be homogeneous (in fact being homogeneous and containing only arcs as proper subcontinua characterizes solenoids among continua).

Planar homogeneous continua are classified: by a 2018 result of Hoehn-Oversteegen they are $S^1$, the pseudoarc and a space known as the circle of pseudoarcs, so solenoids are not planar (except for $S^1$ which is a very special solenoid of course).

Even without the full classification it is a 1960 result of Bing that the only homogeneous planar continuum containing an arc is $S^1$, which also rules out solenoids.